# Authenticating to MySQL with asymmetric key-pair

Tags: mysql, authentication, public-key

Is there anyway I can give MySQL a public key to authenticate vs (or in addition to) username/password authentication?

It seems that you can switch out the backend of where MySQL stores/checks credentials but not how you authenticate.